# How to remove an existing Figure and add another Figure in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on developing a software in python Tkinter and I have a given a Frame. Inside the Frame, I have added a canvas. To the canvas, I have managed to show the figure in the canvas, but I'm not able to remove the figure again and add another figure to the same canvas.

I'm using the code provided below:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4, 4))
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot(p, 'b-', linewidth = 1)
    a.plot(v, x, "*", color = 'red')

    a.set_title ("Data", fontsize=14)
    a.set_ylabel("Unit", fontsize=12)
    a.set_xlabel("Time(s)", fontsize=12)  

    canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.Canvas2)
    # self.Canvas1.place(relx=0.047, rely=0.392, relheight=0.368, relwidth=0.408)
    canvas2.draw()  
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas2, self.Canvas2)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    fig.delaxes(a)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4, 4))
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot(p, 'b-', linewidth = 1)
    a.plot(v, x, "*", color = 'red')

    a.set_title ("New Data", fontsize=14)
    a.set_ylabel("Unit", fontsize=12)
    a.set_xlabel("Time(s)", fontsize=12)  

    canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.Canvas2)
    canvas2.draw()  
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas2, self.Canvas2)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the `canvas`, or you simply want to clear the data and re-use it?

Comment: I want to remove the canvas an add another canvas